# Create a plot for a third variable with x and y axis labels?

Tags: r, plot, graphic

I'm trying to plot something similar to this [graphic](http://www.frames.gov/documents/catalog/alexander_heathcott_schwanke_2013.pdf), see p.32, figure 14.

[image]

Seems quite simple, but I have not been able to find a specific example through online searching. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: look at function `image` to do that in base R.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-expand.grid(x=LETTERS,y=1:20)
df$var<-runif(nrow(df))    

ggplot(df[sample(1:nrow(df),200),]) + theme_bw() + # subset of df to include blanks
  geom_tile(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=var)) + #geom_tile
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="green",mid="yellow",high="red",midpoint=0.5) + # add fill gradient
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=1:20,labels=1:20) +
  coord_fixed(ylim=c(0.5,20.5))
```

you can tinker with the `scale_fill...` functions to acheive whatever layout you want, either based on var (continuous or discrete), or some set of rules.

[image]